McAfee keeps removing OpenVPN TAP
On some of my clients, I have an OpenVPN service running on their server+client machines.
Recently on some clients that install McAfee together with McAfee Safe Connect, OpenVPN stops working because its TAP is simply gone. I even use different OpenVPN versions from client to client, from 2.4.6 to the most recent one and the effects are the same.
I have checked and based on evidence from eventvwr VS openvpn logs, this happens every time McAfee updates its database, updating it manually doesn't do it, but whenever it's the automatic one, the TAP is removed.
Any idea what I can do to tackle this issue?

Stop using McAffee? What does it get you that Defender doesn't?

@DrMoishePippik this is a problem on client machines which i do not control
